# Wrapper for testing Poco HTTPServer handleRequest not compiling.

Tags: c++, poco, poco-libraries

I am trying to write a wrapper to test a http server implemented using Poco. The server is implemented using a subclass of HTTPRequestHandler and has the handleRequest method implemented. The handleRequest method takes two arguments HTTPServerRequest and HTTPServerResponse.

```
handleRequest(HTTPServerRequest& request, HTTPServerResponse& response)
```

These are both abstract classes.  In my wrapper, I need to call the handleRequest method directly. Something like this :

```
req_handler->handleRequest(&req, &res);
```

The way i want to populate the request is using the read() method which is inherited from HTTPRequest, the parent class for HTTPServerRequest. Like this:

```
HTTPServerRequest req = new HTTPServerRequest();
char* buffer //populate this from std::cin 
std::istringstream iss(buffer);
try {
      req->read(iss);
}
```

But the problem is that I cant directly call "new" for HTTPServerRequest / HTTPServerResponse since they are abstract classes. I tried using the HTTPServerRequestImpl but it gives compile error that the pure virtual functions are not implemented, and HTTPServerRequestImpl doesn't have an empty constructor either. I tried this :

```
HTTPServerRequest req  = new HTTPServerRequestImpl()
```

This too gives compiler error as expected. So what is the correct way to write such a wrapper ? How is it done ideally when writing a server in Poco. ? I just want a minimalist wrapper that calls handleRequest with a request populated from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for direct use of HTTPServerRequest. Use [HTTPClientSession](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPClientSession.html) and [HTTPRequest](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Net.HTTPRequest.html):

```
HTTPClientSession s("host", port);
HTTPRequest request(HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, "/");
std::string body("hello world\r\n0\r\n");
request.setContentLength((int) body.length());
s.sendRequest(request) << body;
HTTPResponse response;
std::istream& rs = s.receiveResponse(response);
// ...
```